# Input text field instead of drop down for combinations on product page

Tags: javascript, php, html, smarty

In prestashop 1.6 you have just 2 option for display the combinations to select. Radio button or drop down list. I have 2 attribute, width and lenght. The values from 50 to 300 steb by 1 cm. It's too huge to display in drop down list. I really need a souliton to change the drop down list to input text field.

The piece of code from product.tpl( this display on front end on product page):

```
   <!-- attributes -->
            <div id="attributes">
            {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
                {if $group.attributes|@count}
                    <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset form-group">
                        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}">     {$group.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} :&nbsp;</label>
                        {assign var="groupName" value="group_$id_attribute_group"}
                        <div class="attribute_list">
                        {if ($group.group_type == 'select')}
                            <select name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="attribute_select form-control" onchange="findCombination();getProductAttribute();">
                                {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                    <option value="{$id_attribute|intval}"{if (isset($smarty.get.$groupName) && $smarty.get.$groupName|intval == $id_attribute) || $group.default == $id_attribute} selected="selected"{/if} title="{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$group_attribute|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</option>
                                {/foreach}
                            </select>
```

May have to do some changes in js too.

Comment: The HTML5 `range` input may be suitable in this case. It falls back to a standard `text` input if the browser does not support it. http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php

Comment: Thanks, but in this case it's not a suitable solution. I need an input text field, this is the most confortable for the customer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery number-updown plugin its useful for your case and has many options.

Link for the plugin in github [Link](https://github.com/nakupanda/number-updown)

Examples [Link](http://nakupanda.github.io/number-updown/)

Comment: Thanks, this is an intresting thing, a like it. For now , i can create input field, but the system not handle it. In fontend i see the text field and i can type there but no result, not find the combination. Obviously i have to modify the product.js but i not find exactly what and how, yet.